# How do you handle instantiation of Messages classes in GWT?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I have a question on how you usually instantiate GWT Messages. I usually do this:

```
private static final GenericMessages GENERIC_MESSAGES = GWT.create(GenericMessages.class);
```

I usually do this in every class that uses the GenericMessages Interface, is this a nice thing to do, or should I create a MessagesSingleton that instantiates all my Messages interface and I just access it from there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it. The GWT compiler will replace all your GENERIC_MASSAGES inside the code.

Example:
If you have in your propert file:

```
applicationName=My Application
```

and in your java class like this:

```
label.setText(GENERIC_MESSAGES.applicationName());
```

in compilation time the gwt compiler will replace to

```
label.setText("My Application");
```

and will remove your variable.

Comment: So i don't need to worry for the instantiation overhead since the compiler will just replace all this with Strings? Sorry I just wanted to optimize or know the best practices when instantiating Messages in GWT.

Comment: Exactly the compiler will take care for you. But you can optimize and will make your code clear and the compiler will work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks man. I was worrying for nothing. :) But I would still create a static class I guess just to make the code cleaner.